# Java и mysql udf

Tags: java, mysql

Как написать свою UDF для mysql на java? (для желающих больших вопросов добавлено) - нужны ссылки как надо написать на java, а не на С, что вызывать, как обращаться, что устанавливать....
либо ссылки на утверждение что это не позволяет оракл..

Comment: что тут можно добавлять? что тут может быть непонятного? слишком коротко? - краткость сестра таланта... ответом может быть и ссвлки на туториалы, вариант который дал Anton Shchyrov.

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Для MySQL UDF пишутся в виде нативных dll/so. Java такие dll создавать не может.

Конечно, как вариант, Вы можете написать dll на нативном языке, а эта dll будет дергать Java классы через JNI. Но, имхо, задача не стоит таких извращений

Comment: Я бы не стал так категорино утверждать - есть примеры : http://hive.praveendeshmane.co.in/hive/hive-user-defined-functions-UDF-java-example.jsp  / http://freshmeat.sourceforge.net/projects/judf/?topic_id=66 . Интересует более простой вариант  под окна и под линуксы.

Comment: @Вадим Я там ничего не увидел. Проект мертв с 2003 года. Скачать невозможно. Вероятнее всего в проекте сделана прослойка MySQL <-> JNI о чем я и сказал

Comment: но http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html свежак, и китайцы на его основе делают.

Comment: даже мелкомягкие https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-hive-java-udf используют и другие проекты есть https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/impala_udf.html

Comment: вот вроде туториал https://snowplowanalytics.com/blog/2013/02/08/writing-hive-udfs-and-serdes/

Comment: @Вадим И где во всех Ваших ссылках слово MySQL?

Comment: к примеру тут http://hive.praveendeshmane.co.in/hive/hive-2-1-0-installation-with-mysql-database-on-ubuntu-14-04.jsp, и если учесть что это под лиуксами , то мало вероятно что это mssql

Comment: @Вадим Система использует MySQL как свою внутреннюю СУБД. Ни о каких UDF к MySQL речи не идет.

Comment: вот тут https://www.linux.org.ru/news/opensource/449731 говорят что есть... но это было давно...

Comment: @Вадим `В данном случае, ребята написали мост с C UDF (который в мускуле есть давно) в Java` что и требовалось доказать

Comment: похоже mysql убрал java  из списка возможных языков. куча ссылок есть на java+mysql, но все показывают 404 на сайте mysql...:(

Comment: вот вроде делают https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?12,652199,652199, точнее пытаются ... а вот и инструкция https://bitbucket.org/dejard/dejard.bitbucket.org/src/569e745e0f2c32e2c5745b6e2cd152614449b4ee/index.html?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default но...повторить как? а тут https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/weblinux2/mysql/ch14_01.htm даже утверждают